# Why am I getting the "Fail" response?

Tags: python, printing

I’m wracking my brain to see what I did here.
No matter what, I get the fail print out at the end of the code. I know I'm missing something simple but what? Please help.

```
import random as rand
import time
count = 0

name = input("What is your name? ")
welcome_statement = print( "Welcome,", name, ",to the games!")
rpsls = input("Ready to begin? [Y/N] ").lower()
if rpsls == "Y":
    rules = input("Are you familiar with the rules? [Y/N] ")
    if rules == "Y":
        print ("Starting...")
        time.sleep(3)
        comp_action = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"]
        user_input = input( 'Take a guess: ')
        if user_input == comp_action:
            print("TIE")
else:
    print("Fail")
```

Comment: Take a closer look at what you're doing with `rpsls`.

Comment: The `.lower()` of a string cannot be equal to `"Y"` which is a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.lower()` as following :

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
welcome_statement = print( "Welcome,", name, ",to the games!")
rpsls = input("Ready to begin? [Y/N] ")
if rpsls == "Y":
    rules = input("Are you familiar with the rules? [Y/N] ")
    if rules == "Y":
        print ("Starting...")
        time.sleep(3)
        comp_action = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"]
        user_input = input( 'Take a guess: ')
        if user_input == comp_action:
            print("TIE")
else:
    print("Fail")
```

OR, change `.lower()` to `.upper()` as following :

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
welcome_statement = print( "Welcome,", name, ",to the games!")
rpsls = input("Ready to begin? [Y/N] ").upper()
if rpsls == "Y":
    rules = input("Are you familiar with the rules? [Y/N] ")
    if rules == "Y":
        print ("Starting...")
        time.sleep(3)
        comp_action = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"]
        user_input = input( 'Take a guess: ')
        if user_input == comp_action:
            print("TIE")
else:
    print("Fail")
```